# How to calculate the limit of $\frac {2x^2+x-1}{x^2}$?

Tags: limits

How do I calculate the limit of $\frac {2x^2+x-1}{x^2}$ when $x$ approaches $0$?

What I do is I immediately check what happens when $x$ approaches $0+$ and when $x$ approaches $0-$ and then on both limits I get $-\infty$.

But I feel like I'm doing something wrong. What am I missing?

Comment: That looks right to me.

Comment: Shouldn't I try to divide by $x$ first? If not why?

Comment: Because $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} {x \over x^2}$ does not exist. You can only break up limits and use the addition property if the new limits exist.

Answer (score 1):

Both limits are $-\infty$, yes. That means that the total limit also exists (well, the generalized limit anyway) and is $-\infty$.

You did nothing wrong, you just did not make the final simple step.

Comment: Thanks.But why don't I need to divide by $x$? The teacher taught us that if we get $\frac {c}{0}$ we first need to divide somehow and only then check the limits for $0+$ and $0-$

Comment: @SaharAvr You don't need to divide by $x$ because the top function, $2x^2 + x - 1$, does not have a limit of $0$ as $x\to 0$. If it did, you could not conclude that the limit exists.

Comment: I don't understand... what does it mean that it doesn't have a limit of 0?

Comment: @SaharAvr The limit of $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ is a problem if the limit of $f(x)$ and of $g(x)$ are both $0$. In your case, the lmit of $f(x)$ is equal to $1$, so there is no problem.

Comment: So whenever x approaches to a finite number and I have a limit of $\frac{natural-number}{0}$ I can immediately spread to two limits of x+ and x- ?

Answer (score 1):

With equivalents:
$$2x^2+x-1\sim_0 -1,\enspace\text{hence}\quad \frac{2x^2+x-1}{x^2}\sim_0 \frac{-1}{x^2}\xrightarrow[x\to0_{\scriptstyle\pm}]{}-\infty.$$

Comment: Thank you... I'm still not advanced enough to understand what you wrote though

Comment: ‘Equivalent function’ (in the neighbourhood of a point $a$) simply means that their ratio tends to $1$ when $x$  tends to $a$. A classic result is apolynomial is equivalent to its highest degree term in a neighbourhood of $\infty$, and equivalent to its lowest degree term in a neighbourhood of $0$. It is a way to remove unrelated details.